# Creating delegating methods in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Suppose I am writing a method that delegates part of its work to an existing method (A factory method invoking a constructor would be a good example).

I would like to be able to automatically add the arguments to the method I am writing based on the method it invokes. However, IntelliJ does not seem to have the right shortcut for this. For example:

I have

```
class Foo {
    Foo(ArgClass arg);
}
```

and I've just created

```
class FooFactory {
    Foo createFoo() {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

Is there a shortcut (or a sequence of them) that would get my factory to

```
class FooFactory {
    Foo createFoo(ArgClass arg) {
        return new Foo(arg);
    }
}
```

**without manually typing** "arg"?

Comment: can't you use code -> delegate methods ?? that feature is there right?/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing it like this. Copy & paste `arg` once here (| is text cursor):

```
class FooFactory {
    Foo createFoo() {
        return new Foo(arg|);
    }
}
```

Invoke <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and select the quick fix `Create parameter 'arg'`. The Change Signature refactoring dialog appears, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept. Result:

```
class FooFactory {
    Foo createFoo(ArgClass arg) {
        return new Foo(arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Typing "arg" is what I am trying to avoid. With many function arguments having long meaningful names, this can get pretty tedious pretty fast.

Comment: use copy & paste?

Comment: Sure, that's a solution.